# Database design - How much data to store, performance vs quality

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

There is some value, x, which I am recording every 30 seconds, currently into a database with three fields:

- ID
- Time
- Value

I am then creating a mobile app which will use that data to plot charts in views of:

- Last hour
- Last 24 hours.
- 7 Day
- 30 Day
- Year

Obviously, saving every 30 seconds for the last year and then sending that data to a mobile device will be too much (it would mean sending 1051200 values).
My second thought was perhaps I could use the average function in MySQL, for example, collect all of the averages for every 7 days (creating 52 points for a year), and send those points. This would work, but still MySQL would be trawling through creating averages and if many users connect, it's going to be bad.

So simply put, if these are my views, then I do not need to keep track of all that data. Nobody should care what x was a year ago to the precision of every 30 seconds, this is fine. I should be able to use "triggers" to create some averages.

I'm looking for someone to check what I have below is reasonable:

- Store values every 30s in a table (this will be used for the hour view, 120 points)
- When there are 120 rows are in the 30s table (120 * 30s = 60 mins = 1 hour), use a trigger to store the first half an hour in a "half hour average" table, remove the first 60 entries from the 30s table. This new table will need to have an id, start time, end time and value. This half hour average will be used for the 24 hour view (48 data points).
- When the half hour table has more than 24 entries (12 hours), store the first 6 as an average in a 6 hour average table and then remove from the table. This 6 hour average will be used for the 7 day view (28 data points).
- When there are 8 entries in the 6 hour table, remove the first 4 and store this as an average day, to be used in the 30 day view (30 data points).
- When there are 14 entries in the day view, remove the first 7 and store in a week table, this will be used for the year view.

This doesn't seem like the best way to me, as it seems to be more complicated than I would imagine it should be.

The alternative is to keep all of the data and let mysql find averages as and when needed. This will create a monstrously huge database. I have no idea about the performance yet. The id is an int, time is a datetime and value is a float. Is 1051200 records too many? Now is a good time to add, I would like to run this on a raspberry pi, but if not.. I do have my main machine which I could use.

Comment: you are looking for some RRD fun here.

Comment: 1051200 records is nothing, especially with a database with few columns such as yours, and with correct indexes you shouldn't notice performance issues.

Comment: Agreed, just over a million records is nothing to most RDBMSs (even some of the in-memory ones, especially if that's your only table - which is around 36MB of raw data).  The one thing I'd want to avoid on a mobile system is carrier data limits, if you're downloading the raw data to a device (whole thing daily - if rows, it's trivially sized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed design looks OK. Perhaps there are more elegant ways of doing this, but your proposal should work too.

RRD (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-Robin_Database) is a specialised database designed to do all of this automatically, and it should be much more performant than MySQL for this specialised purpose.

An alternative is the following: keep only the original table (1051200 records), but have a trigger that generates the last hour/day/year etc views every time a new record is added (e.g. every 30 seconds) and store/cache the result somewhere. Then your number-crunching workload is independent of the number of requests/clients you have to serve.

1051200 records may or may not be too many. Test in your Raspberry Pi to find out.

Comment: I will look into RRD. The simplest solutions are often the best, I love the idea of basing the trigger on the insert (every 30 seconds). After looking at RRD, i'll see which one is best, but I suspect the i'll go with using the insert as trigger to calculate all of the points needed. I am in my head combining your advice with that of Stanyer, who suggests 1051200 records isn't as horrible as I original thought. My issue is that I have messed with databases, but never needed to store this many records.

Comment: Just storing or processing this many records is not a problem in itself. I have had databases with 200M+ rows, and running queries on them that take in the whole table too. The question is how fast you need it to be... if the query is limited to running just once every 30 seconds, then it should be manageable even on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score -1):

Let me give a suggestion on the physical layout of your table, regardless on whether you decide to keep all data or "prune" it from time to time...

Since you generate a new row "every 30 seconds", then `Time` can serve as a natural key without fear of exceeding the resolution of the underlying data type and causing duplicated keys. You don't need `ID` in this scenario<sup>1</sup>, so your table is simply:

```
Time (PK)
Value
```

And since [InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/), not having secondary indexes<sup>2</sup> means the whole table is stored in a **single B-Tree**, which is as efficient as it gets from storage and querying perspective. On top of that, `Value` is automatically [covered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index), which may not have been the case in your original design unless you specifically designed your index(es) for that.

Using time as key can be tricky in general, but I think may be worth it in this particular case.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Unless there are other tables that reference it through FOREIGN KEYs, or you have already written too much code that depends on it.*

*<sup>2</sup> Which would be necessary in the original design to support efficient aggregation.*

Comment: What about when it is rolled out to multiple time zones or additional instances of the generator are added? I'd say having a surrogate key is a good idea in most situations, to save having to re-do the clustered index if something changes... and it's not like the few bytes saved is going to have much impact, especially if they do end up aggregating every so often and getting rid of them anyway... (also doesn't attempt answer question atall :S )

Comment: @Milney Regarding "additional timezones/generators", see: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it). When you do (need it), it won't be too difficult to refactor. Regarding "few more bytes", we are talking about the entire new B-Tree, effectively doubling the "bytes" (and/or introducing potential for [double-lookup](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)). And as I stated in my answer, I was concentrating on the "physical layout", which, I'm sure you'll agree, is an important consideration in any database model...